# Return 403 if route is not allowed

Tags: php, laravel-5.5

I have Route group with middleware (I use [Zizaco/entrust](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust) package):

```
Route::group(['as' => 'admin.', 'prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function (){
    ...
});
```

When I try to enter `http://mysite/admin` while not authenticated I get exception

> Symfony \ Component \ HttpKernel \ Exception \ HttpException
>   No message

But I want to return 403.
I tried to do this:

```
Route::fallback(function(){
    abort(403);
});
```

but it didn't helped.

---

Edit 1: here we have [exception handle](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.5/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php#L934) in Laravel 5.5.28

```
public function abort($code, $message = '', array $headers = [])
    {
        if ($code == 404) {
            throw new NotFoundHttpException($message);
        }

        throw new HttpException($code, $message, null, $headers);
    }
```

As you can see, there is no `403` handle.

Comment: 404 is Not Found though

Comment: @kerbholz thank you, I've improved my question

Answer (score 0):

you have to modify [handle](https://github.com/Zizaco/entrust/blob/master/src/Entrust/Middleware/EntrustRole.php#L36:5) method of role middleware

```
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $roles)
{
    if (!is_array($roles)) {
        $roles = explode(self::DELIMITER, $roles);
    }
    if ($this->auth->guest() || !$request->user()->hasRole($roles)) {
        abort(403); // notice here it returns 403
    }
    return $next($request);
}
```

Comment: `Undefined class constant 'DELIMITER'`

Comment: By the way I changed `403` to `404` and I get `404` as expected. But why Laravel does not handle `403` than?

Comment: const DELIMITER = '|';

Comment: @DoIGetAnything please have 403 page in your  errors views